# How to Convert Array to String[] in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, null

```
string[] B = C.OfType<object>().Where(o =>o  != null).Select(o => o.ToString()).ToArray();
```

I try to Convert Array `C` to `string[]`
but, Array `C` have a lot of `null` and I hope `null` change to `" "`
What Should I do?

Comment: try this
string[] B = C.OfType<string>().Where(o =>o  != null).Select(o => o.ToString()).ToArray();

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `OfType<object>()`, simply call [string.Concat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9c94ey1(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var s = string.Concat(C.ToArray());
```

If you look at documentation:

> The method concatenates each object in args by calling the parameterless ToString method of that object; it does not add any delimiters.
>   String.Empty is used in place of any null object in the array.'

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var B = C.OfType<string>().Select(o => o ?? " ").ToArray();
```

`.OfType<string>()` will filter out all non-string values from C.

`.Select(o => o ?? " ")` will select the value, or `" "` if the value was null.

and `.ToArray()` will take the IEnumerable and turn it into a `string[]`.